# C undefined reference to `some_foo'

Tags: c, makefile, autoconf

I have 3 files in my gtk+ app:

main.c:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gi18n.h>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MainWin*      win;
    GError* err = NULL;
    int a = 0;
    a = some_foo();
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

mainwindo.h

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


typedef struct _MainWin
{
    GtkWindow parent;

} MainWin;

GtkWidget* main_win_new();

int some_foo();
```

MainWindow.c

```
#include "mainwindow.h"


int some_foo()
{
  return 1;
}
```

When i try to call `some_foo` in main function, and try to compile i see error: undefined reference to `some_foo'. What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: which compiler/commands were you using?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not including MainWindow.c in your build. How do you build your project?

Comment: Have you considered just using a Makefile? Its very likely that your project will grow beyond one or two files. If you need help writing one, update your question. Also, can't resist ... So long, and thanks for all the foo.

Comment: I suspect, you have a mixture of C++/C symbols in your program. try to use `extern "C" { #include "mainwindow.h" }` in your C code. If it does not help, give us a dump of `make` output plus `nm MainWindow.o` plus `nm main.o`.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably not including `MainWindow.c` in your build. E.g. in the shell it could look like this:

```
gcc $ALL_THE_FLAGS main.c MainWindow.c
```

Comment: I compile with makefile. This makefile generated by autoconf. And it very big. How can o include mainwindow.c file?

Comment: You have to look in your `Makefile.in` in that case and add the source and the object file there. If that file is shorter, maybe copy it into the question? Alternatively there are services like pastebin. @sterh

Comment: @sterh: could you add your Makefile.am file? it should be more readable

Comment: @sterh: In your `Makefile.am` you've got `MainWindow.c` in lower case (`mainwindow.c`), but in your question you've got it capitalized - are you sure you haven't got another file called `mainwindow.c` which is being built instead?  (I'm assuming you're on linux or some similar system where filenames are case sensitive).

Comment: @sterh The Makefile is not generated by autoconf.  The makefile is generated by the configure script from Makefile.in, and the Makefile.in is generated by automake.